# Iterator Class Not Incrementing Value Python

Tags: python, iterator

I am using an Iterator class to generate a geometric progression. When I compile the code it runs the correct number of times but the value of my iterator does not change from the first value. For example if I input 5 for the number of terms, 2 for the first term, and 3 for the common ratio the program will output 2 five times. What have I messed up?

```
class geo_p:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.a = int(input('Enter the first term:'))
        self.d = int(input('Enter the common ratio:'))
        self.i = self.a
        self.n = n

    def _iter_(self):
        return self

    def _next_(self):
            i = 1
            if i < self.n:
                #sets curr = to the current term in progression
                current = self.i
                self.i = (self.i * (self.d**(i-1))) 
                i +=1
                return current

            else:
                raise StopIteration()

y = geo_p
n = int(input('Enter the number of terms: '))
y.__init__(y, n)
print(y)
for i in range (n):
    print(y._next_(y))
```

Comment: why using a class instead of a generator function?

Comment: Did you mean `__iter__` and `__next__` ?

Comment: And why do you have `y = geo_p` and then `y.__init__(y, n)`? it makes no sense at all. Just do `y = geo_p(n)`

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.  You need to repeat your tutorial on this topic and follow the examples therein.  You're trying to use `y` as a class, an instance, and a value.  You have implemented your own methods (single underscores) instead of the standard iterator naming (double underscores).

Comment: You seem fundamentally confused about the point of iterators/iterables. `print(y._next_(y))` **don't call special methods directly**. If you *did* want to do this, use `next(y)`, but actually, the *whole point* of an iterator is that you can do `for x in y: print(x)`

Comment: `y.__init__(y, n)` that's totally wrong, `y` is the *class* `geo_p`, you never instantiated anything, and if you did, you should never be calling `__init__` like that (from outside the class, barring very specific circumstances).

Comment: Sorry for my poor question. The book I am following does not do a great job of elaborating on the specific syntax of iterators. I did not realize there was a difference between `_next_` and `__next__`. Based on the rest of the comments it seems I lack some knowledge of fundamental concepts. I will go back and review. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`i` is always 1 (at the top of `__next__`)

1-0 is always zero

anything raised to the zero is 1 (@ `self.d**(i-1)`)

so you end up with `self.i = self.i * 1`

but as the comments on this answer and the original question point out ... you have other issues ... but this is why `self.i` is not incrementing when you call `_next_()`

Comment: A large part of the problem is that OP does not even has `__next__` ...

Comment: he does... i think ... his indents are just wrong (because he didnt know how to add code blocks to stackoverflow (I assume)) .,.. but it sounds like he is iterating and printing something  in his real code ... so i just assumed there were typos in the transcription

Comment: They have `_next_`, which is not the same as `__next__`. Same goes to for `_iter_`

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding. I realize the mistake I made. It seems I have a fundamental misunderstanding of some key concepts that I will need to review. Thank you for your answer.